# Trigger "console.log" with message "onfocusleave" in select element directive with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I build this directives for AngularJS+Symfony2 project:

```
app.directive('country', ['$http', function($http) {
        return {
            restrict: "C",
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                $http.get(Routing.generate('countries')).success(function(data) {
                    if (data.message) {
                        scope.message = data.message;
                    } else {
                        scope.countries = data.entities;
                    }
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    if (status == '500') {
                        scope.message = "There is not connection with server";
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }]);

app.directive('state', ['$http', '$parse', function($http, $parse) {
        return {
            restrict: "C",
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(attrs.trigger, function() {
                    state = $parse(attrs.trigger)(scope);
                    iso = state != undefined && state.iso_country != undefined ? state.iso_country : state;
                    if (iso !== undefined && iso !=='') {
                        $http.get(Routing.generate('states') + '/' + iso).success(function(data) {
                            if (data.message) {
                                scope.message = data.message;
                            } else {
                                scope.states = data.entities;
                            }
                        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            if (status == '500') {
                                scope.message = "There is not connection with server";
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

And this is how I use in my template file:

```
<select class="country"
        ng-model = "country.standard_address"
        ng-options = "country.name for country in countries">
    <option value="-1">{{ "Select country" | trans }}</option>
</select>
<select class="state"
        ng-model = "state.standard_address"
        ng-disabled = "!states"
        ng-options = "state.name for state in states"
        trigger = "country.standard_address">
    <option value="-1">{{ "Select state" | trans }}</option>
</select>
```

I need to add some way to validate this fields in case user didn't change it and remain with value equal `-1`. I could do this on click event for submit button but I not enabled the button until the form has no errors. This is the code to handle this part:

```
<input type="button" class="button {% verbatim %}{{ step1Form.$valid && 'active' || 'gray'}}{% endverbatim %}" value="Continuar" ng-disabled="!step1Form.$valid" ng-click="nextStep(2)" />
```

how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting **[the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)** on `select` (with `ngOptions`):

*Optionally, a single hard-coded  element, with the value set to an empty string, can be nested into the  element. This element will then represent the null or "not selected" option.*

You need to set the value of the hard-coded `option` to an empty string and add the `required` attribute to the select elements. This way, the `step1Form` will not be valid unless an option (other than the null option) is selected.

---

**UPDATE:**

Seems like I misunderstood yur requirements. In order to be able to display a message on `blur`, you can use `ng-focus` and `ng-blur` to set the value of a variable. Then have an element that is shown/hidden based on the value of that variable (also taking into account the validity of the select).
The code for the "country" select could look like this:

```
<select name="countrySelect" ng-model="country.standard_address"
        ng-options = "country.name for country in countries"
        ng-focus="countryFocused=true" ng-blur="countryFocused=false"
        required>
        <option value="">Select country</option>
</select>
<div ng-hide="countryFocused || step1Form.countrySelect.$valid">
    ERROR !!! Select a country ASAP !
</div>
```

See, also, this (updated) **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/9JV2p/)**.

Comment: I have this part done, what I trying to do is to show some kind of message if user leave this field without change the default option, any advice on this one?

Comment: @ReynierPM: Please, take a look at my updated answer and demo.